# Software to delete lines in a text file

Tags: windows, text-processing, plain-text

I'm looking for a windows software which can bulk delete lines in text files after a specific line.

For example, a file contains 5 lines. I want to delete lines after the third line. see:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
xxxxxx
xxxxxx1
```

Here, I want to keep first 3 lines(line 1, line 2, line 3) and delete remaining 2 lines(xxxxxx, xxxxxx1) and automatically save that text file. I want to do this to multiple text files. Want to delete every line after the 3rd line in every text file inside a folder.

Any windows software for this?

Comment: Please note that asking for software to do X is on-topic at this site but asking how to do something with software (Can I do this with Notepad++) is off-topic - you should direct that specific question at SuperUser.

Comment: That wasn't my only question. I asked for a software and if notepad++ can do this and somebody knows how to do it, I don't think that creates any problem for anybody.

Comment: [Linked Discussion](http://superuser.com/q/1068371/269798)

Answer (score 2):

[GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) is able to do it, e.g. `sed`. At the command line, type

```
for %f in ("*.txt") do C:\...\sed -i "1,3!d" "%f"
```

The `for` command is part of the Windows command line. `%f` defines a variable to hold the file name. `in ("*.txt")` defines which files to process. `do C:\...\sed` tells Windows to run a command.

`-i` will perform in-place operation, i.e. write to the same file. `1,3` defines a range of lines, `!` chooses all other lines, `d` deletes them and `"%f"` passes the file to be processed to SED, so it knows which file to process.

GnuWin runs on Windows and is free.

Comment: Consider using `-i.bak` which will create a backup of all files before changing them (with the .bak extenstion).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without installing software but instead creating a simple batch script. Here's a script that will do what you want:

```
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
set/p D=delete all after what line?
set N=
:main
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (file.txt) do (
set/a N+=1
if !N! leq !D! echo.%%a
) >> NEWFILE
```

Where `file.txt` is the actual file. When you execute this script, it will ask you what line to delete after, simply say `3`. Copy the above code and paste it in a `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this using basic Unix/Linux tools.

I'd recommend to use [awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk) in your case. To run awk on windows, you can use [a Windows port of awk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

My personal experience is the it pays quickly to learn awk if you have to do text processing from time to time.